# Scala script not execute on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, scala

I install scala on my Mac. The scala shell works well. But the scala script can not execute, not even a most simple one like this:

hello.scala

```
println("hello world")
```

Then run it

```
scala hello.scala
```

Nothing happens and cmd seems working until I click <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

However,if I use

```
scala -nc hello.scala
```

it executes and output "hello world" as I expected.

And if I change the script like:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala "$0" "$@"
!#
println("Hello world")
```

It also can not work with "./hello.scala"

What problem is in it? I have never face this problem on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the script from the *command line*, not from the Scala REPL.
I am using OSX 10.13, and Scala 2.12.4

I have a file Hello.scala with the following content

```
println("HelloWorld!")
```

To run the script, simply type:

```
Agatas-MacBook-Pro:$ scala Hello.scala
```

The output is:

```
HelloWorld!
```